# Using Authorization methods on a nested Resource

Tags: tastypie

Is it possible for tastypie to understand that I want it to use the same authorization methods for filtering out objects from a nested Resource?

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user) # return projects only the user created

class ProjectGroupResource(ModelResource):
    projects = ToManyField(
        ProjectResource,
        attribute='projects',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

The `authorized_read_list` method doesn't fire when accessing the `ProjectGroupResource`, so I get all projects, including non-user created ones. I was under the assumption that since I'm passing a ProjectResource ref, it would attempt to simulate a get_object_list, which should trigger authorized_read_list with the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with Tastypie, but I think the `authorized_*` methods only apply to that Resource when used directly, not when a Resource is used to serialize a related attribute.

It looks like your `authorized_read_list` method is missing a return `statement` though.

Comment: Edited to add the return statement